# How to change salutation for multiple recipients in Outlook with c#

Tags: outlook-addin

I want to code an outlook addin and try to replace a placeholder in an outlook mail with the salutation of the recipient. I get the salutation from AD. I tried this in ItemSend, but the body for different recipients contains always the last replacement.
Then i generated a new mail per recipient. That seems to be the right way, but there is the next problem. The mailitem.htmlbody contains not the same content like shown in the outlook message window. All styles of the original message are lost and for instance my signature is bad formatted.

Has anyone an idea to solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if want to send an individual "salutation" for each recipient you need to send separate emails. For example, you can check out the list of recipients in the ItemSend event and if it contacts more than one entry in the collection you can cancel the send operation setting the Cancel parameter to true and prepare an individual email to each recipient from the collection.

You may consider using the Word object model instead of modifying the raw HTML markup of the body. The WordEditor of the Inspector class returns an instance of the Document class from the Word object model. The [Chapter 17: Working with Item Bodies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492012%28v=office.12%29.aspx) describes all possible ways of working with item bodies.